# Annotating page links with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am doing the Lynda.com jQuery Essential Training by Joe Marini. Chapter 2, Practical example for annotating page links. This is to add a small icon gif next to any page links that are .pdf files. I am using jquery-1.10.2.min.js. Following the instructions, the code as I typed it is:

```
$(“document”).ready(function() {
        $(“a[href$=.pdf]”).after(“<img src=’images/small_pdf_icon.gif’ align=’absbottom’ />”);
});
```

which returns this error in the java console in Chrome:
**Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href$=.pdf]**
Sorry, couldn't post a screen shot of the lesson. No reputation yet.

Am I just typing this incorrectly? Or could it have changed since this lesson was made with and earlier version of jquery? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to escape the dot with two backslashes `\\`

The selector would be `$(“a[href$=\\.pdf]”)`

From [official docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar")

**EDIT**

Adding quotes around `.pdf` would work too as @Cherniv and @zzzzBov pointed out

Answer (score 2):

Or just wrap this `.pdf` with a single quotes:

```
 $("a[href$='.pdf']").after("<img src=’images/small_pdf_icon.gif’ align=’absbottom’ />");
```

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/RFD6h/

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("a[href$=.pdf]").after("<img src='images/small_pdf_icon.gif' align='absbottom' />");
});
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the difference here, Shivam.

Answer (score 1):

The selector needs to be quoted:

```
$('a[href$=".pdf"]');
```

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/):

> value: An attribute value. Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string.